# Sort on list of objects that contains dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

Here is my object:

```
public class A
{
public string Name { get; set; }    
public Dictionary<int, List<int>> Years { get; set; }
}
```

Dictionary contains list of years then, list of months. I am looking to sort **list of A** by year first then month.

Dictionary sample on each A:

```
{2015,new List(){3,4,5,6}}
{2016,new List(){2,8,9,10}}
```

If I have multiple years then it can sort something like:
2015 then 2015, 2016 then 2016

I failed to implement IComparable or use any existing extension methods like OrderBy or Sort. Thanks!

Comment: How would you sort `A1: ( {10, {0}}, {12, {0}} ), A2: ( {11, {0}}, {13, {0}} )`? Should `A1` go first because the lowest year it has is before the lowest year of `A2`? Or do you split each A up and sort it into one big A like `{10,..}, {11,..}, {12,..}, {13,..}`?

Comment: Yes, A1 first then A2. No split as it will duplicate object A. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added IComparable to your A class ( which of course you can extract and pass as a delegate .....)

[fiddlerlink](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VCtz7s)

**note:** For simplicity i DO assume that the lists are sorted. otherwise add a your sorts at the appropriate place in your scenario :)

basically return the first compare that is not equal years or months.
you can call this by MyListOfAs.Sort();

```
public class A:IComparable<A>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, List<int>> Years { get; set; }

    private int complists(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        var iret = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(a.Count, b.Count))
                     where a[i].CompareTo(b[i]) != 0
                     select a[i] > b[i] ? 1 : -1).FirstOrDefault();

        return iret;
    }
    public int CompareTo(A other)
    {
        var mykeys = this.Years.Keys.ToList();
        var otherkeys = other.Years.Keys.ToList();

        var iret = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(mykeys.Count, otherkeys.Count))
                     let yearDiff = mykeys[i].CompareTo(otherkeys[i])
                     let monthDiff = complists(this.Years[mykeys[0]], other.Years[otherkeys[0]])
                     where yearDiff != 0 || monthDiff != 0
                     select yearDiff != 0 ? yearDiff : monthDiff).FirstOrDefault();

        return iret != 0 ? iret : mykeys.Count > otherkeys.Count ? 1 : mykeys.Count < otherkeys.Count ? -1 : 0;
    }    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Check https://dotnetfiddle.net/w7Sywg Any idea why "a14" not coming on top? It has only 2015.

Comment: in retro spec i think i was wrong ( i updated the solution above )
i changed the from x in a from y in b to an ordinal compare, and then added the count of lists which i didn't take into account the first time :/
i hope this at least gets you on the right ( helpful ) track :)

Comment: Thanks. Its still not working. I added one more object with 2015. Please check fiddle.

Comment: which fiddle link are you referring to?    this one shows a14 first https://dotnetfiddle.net/VCtz7s

Comment: well a19 has 6,8,11,2     which is larger then the others who have 6,7,8,9,10,11 because ( second element is greater )  8>7

a14 is still your first cause it's equal to those who have the same 2015 values but only has one year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80226/discussion-between-manish-jain-and-cechode).

Comment: FYI, this solution only works on sorted data by year and months. If you can tweak your solution, that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it: `listOfA.OrderBy(a => a.Years.Min(y => y.Key + y.Value.Min() / 13d))`

If the lowest year and month in a dictionary is 2000 Jan, for example, it's value would be `2000 + 1/13 = 2000.0769`

Then all that's left is to select the smallest value from each dictionary, and sort them by that.

*Note* that the value `13` can be `20` as well, if you want nicer numbers for some reason, but the biggest fraction of `12/x` must be less than 1 in order to give more importance to the year properly, so `x` must be greater than 12. This assumes that the range of the months is 1 to 12 inclusively.

---

Example I/O:

```
var listOfA = new List<A>
              {
                  new A
                  {
                      Name = "a1",
                      Years = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
                              {
                                  {2015, new List<int> {3, 4, 5, 6}},
                                  {2016, new List<int> {2, 8, 9, 10}}
                              }
                  },
                  new A
                  {
                      Name = "a2",
                      Years = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
                              {
                                  {2013, new List<int> {3, 4, 5, 6}},
                                  {2014, new List<int> {2, 8, 9, 10}}
                              }
                  },
                  new A
                  {
                      Name = "a3",
                      Years = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
                              {
                                  {2015, new List<int> {3, 4, 5, 6}},
                                  {2014, new List<int> {2, 8, 9, 10}}
                              }
                  },
                  new A
                  {
                      Name = "a4",
                      Years = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
                              {
                                  {2014, new List<int> {1, 4, 5, 6}},
                                  {2017, new List<int> {2, 8, 9, 10}}
                              }
                  }
              };

// listOfA is now {a1, a2, a3, a4}
listOfA = listOfA.OrderBy(a => a.Years.Min(y => y.Key + y.Value.Min() / 13d)).ToList();
// listOfA is now {a2, a4, a3, a1}
```

Comment: Thanks Yorye! It's not working for me. Can you add two objects with only 2015 and 2016? Its failing on 2015.

Comment: Share a pastebin of your version and expected order.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - Don't use pastebin - try https://dotnetfiddle.net/ instead. You can actually run the code there.

Comment: @ManishJain I didn't mean share your question-version. I mean share the example in which my code fails. (not to mention, you just created a copy of the fiddler from cechode's answer, thats hardly what I asked for)

Comment: Oops. I modified original code. But, data is still valid.

Comment: Ah, yes. You would probably want to check for the next month if the first ones are equal, and the same for a year of the whole year has the same months. cechode's answer might be better for you. My version only checks the minimum of the year and month, and only compares those.